# Relationship between standard error and confidence interval of AUC

Tags: roc, auc

I apologize if this is a very basic question. When I see a term like AUC 0.72 ± 0.02, what does the number after ± refer to? Is this the standard error?

Secondly, how can I find the 95% confidence interval from the standard error of AUC and vice-versa?